# PHP ent_quotes exception for <br> and <ar>

Tags: php, html-entities

i am trying to covert HTML to entities using PHP, but i need to except <br> and <a>  tags.

here's an example of my code

```
 <?php 
  $string[0] = "<a href='http://hidd3n.tk'>Needs to stay</a> Filler text in between 
 <br><br> <script src='http://malicious.com/'></script> NEEDS to go";
  $string[1] = htmlentities($string[0], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
 ?>
```

Comment: what is your expected output and actual output?

Comment: Desired Output is: <br> where there is a <br> and an <a> where there is an <a> in the string, but everything else is converted into enitites

Comment: Its better you use BBCode as suggested by @Your Common Sense

Comment: @jackrenshaw: Check my new solution.

Answer (score 3):

Let me suggest you to use a [BBCode](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) which will be way more safe.

Comment: -1 for this reckless option. Check the complexity of bbcode. my function is the simplest for the user to apply

Comment: @VIPINJAIN yeah. as well as unsafe one

Comment: @yourcommonsense : check the new solution.:)

Comment: WTF?? [W]Reckless? No... your method is still wreckless. Please take the advise of using BBCode.

Comment: for the exact reason @cHao said. carry on, as you wish, though.

Comment: @VIPINJAIN what if a user put `<a href="regex.php" title="BBCode > Regex">BBCode > Regex</a>`, the outcome becomes `<a href="regex.php" title="BBCode> Regex"&gt;BBCode &gt; Regex</a>`

Answer (score -3):

**EDIT:**

Okay i have worked out a way.

Take this function rather safe than previous one:

```
function convert_myhtml_entities($string){
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $string = preg_replace('/&lt;\s*br\s*(\/|)\s*&gt;/U','<br$1>',$string);
    $string = preg_replace('/&lt;\s*a(.*)\s*&gt;/U','<a$1>',$string);
    $string = preg_replace('/&lt;\s*\/\s*a\s*&gt;/U','</a>',$string);
    return $string;
}
```

now it is the tested with the string above.

Comment: OMG what's this `'##%%br$1%%##'` horror?

Comment: its just the unique string so that it does not conflicts with the text. and u think it as horror :P

Comment: You don't know it doesn't conflict.  Someone could for some reason have `##%%` or `%%##` legitimately in their text.  What's more, `##%%script%%## alert('Oops, you just allowed script injection!'); ##%%/script%%##`

Comment: okay then you can have full tags expression set in the last 2 preg_matches for injection safe parsing. but why to use the functions which require so high processing power????

Comment: Because you're using that extra CPU time to **do things correctly**.    Correctness trumps speed, in 99.8% of all cases.  Screwing up quickly is almost as bad as screwing up slowly, and nowhere near as good as doing the right thing, regardless of how slow it is.  Once it's correct, *then* speed comes into play.

Comment: What's more, if you use an existing popular solution like BBcode, (1) that's time you can spend making your site better instead of rolling your own parsing solution; (2) it's proven it can at least do the job it's meant for, unlike your home-grown let's-pretend-we-can-parse-HTML-with-regex jobbie, and (3) if a bug is ever found, it will generally be fixed very quickly.

Comment: @chao: Check my new solution.

Comment: The second regex doesn't properly see `<a href="/>">` (which is valid syntactically, if useless as a link).

Comment: @chao : but the question specifically says that he wants to preserve <a> and <br> tags only he donot want to validate them. and one more thing BBCODE is used for markup in blogs and forums. where as he wants to parse the html such that those tags are preserved.

Comment: @VIPINJAIN: But your code *doesn't* preserve them.  `<a href="/>">` becomes `<a href="/>"&gt;`.  And in order to prevent that, you'd have to account for when stuff is and isn't valid in HTML.  You'd have to find the end of the link using the rules of syntax...read, *parse HTML*.

Comment: Judging by the content he's trying to filter, it seems to me he's trying to implement some secure way people can post links and have line breaks and such in their comments/posts/whatever.  I'd say BBcode fits that bill rather well.